# is this “a” a print error or an article for to emphasize “one”

Tags: grammaticality

my question in another SE site has been edited as following:

> I've searched in SE for solfege and na
>   mes of altered notes or tones.
>
> This point seems to be cleared. But I couldn't find a about hand-signs
>   for solfege

now I'm not sure why it says: a about ???

Comment: It is not grammatical as it stands. I would say it is a clear typo: there is a noun omitted (probably "post" or "question").

Comment: thank you, I thought it might be emphasizing "a" as "one"

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli: Maybe this was the author's intention, but anyway: Simply replacing "one" by "a" is wrong in the given context.